# How to query all connected devices in build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, adb, build.gradle

I am trying to write a task in build.gradle that executes shell commands on all connected devices. However, when I run my task, I get the notorious 'multiple devices connected' error.

```
task(myTask, type: Exec) {
    doFirst {
        println 'myTask'
        commandLine 'adb', 'shell', 'my command'
    }
}
```

This is understandable, because I did not specify which device to run on with `-s`. However, I noticed that the `installDebug` task will execute its commands on all connected devices (install debug .apk on all devices).

Is there an API in the android plugin that returns a collection of devices IDs that I can iterate over?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.You can check the Android Gradle Plugin [source here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/925c0b5cf8730105dd5aa8c851141d5688d07789/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/tasks/TestFlavorTask.groovy), where you will find the following:

```
import com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge
import com.android.ddmlib.IDevice

// ...    

AndroidDebugBridge.initIfNeeded(false /*clientSupport*/)
AndroidDebugBridge bridge = AndroidDebugBridge.createBridge(android.getAdbExe().absolutePath,
        false /*forceNewBridge*/)

long timeOut = 30000 // 30 sec
int sleepTime = 1000
while (!bridge.hasInitialDeviceList() && timeOut > 0) {
    sleep(sleepTime)
    timeOut -= sleepTime
}
if (timeOut <= 0 && !bridge.hasInitialDeviceList()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Timeout getting device list.", null)
}
IDevice[] devices = bridge.devices
if (devices.length == 0) {
    throw new RuntimeException("No connected devices!", null)
}

File destination = project.file("$project.buildDir/outputs/screenshots")
delete destination

for (IDevice device : devices) {
    // iterate over your devices here ;)
}
```

Also you will notice that there is a getter for adb as well that you can use in the loop from above:

```
project.exec {
            executable = android.getAdbExe()
            args '-s'
            args "$device.serialNumber"
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about how we're supposed to make use of this. That first file is part of the Gradle plugin source. Are you saying that we have to make our own fork of the Android Gradle plugin? How do we access this from `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but maybe it helps someone at some point.

As [David Medenjak](http://David%20Medenjak) already mentioned the android.ddmlib is the solution.
You can use it like the following:

In yourscript.gradle:

```
import com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge
import com.android.ddmlib.IDevice
import com.android.ddmlib.NullOutputReceiver

task pressPower {

    description = "Press the power button of a device using the adb."

    AndroidDebugBridge.initIfNeeded(false)
    def bridge = AndroidDebugBridge.createBridge(android.adbExecutable.path, false)

    doLast {
        bridge.devices.each {
            it.executeShellCommand("input keyevent 26", NullOutputReceiver.receiver)
        }
    }
}
```

In which "input keyevent 26" corresponds to the shell command `./adb shell input keyevent 26.`

If you want to work with the output of the shell you can use the `CollectingOutputReceiver` like below:

```
import com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge
import com.android.ddmlib.IDevice
import com.android.ddmlib.CollectingOutputReceiver

task getAnimationValue {

    description = "Get the Value for the window animation scale."

    AndroidDebugBridge.initIfNeeded(false)
    def bridge = AndroidDebugBridge.createBridge(android.adbExecutable.path, false)
    def receiver = CollectingOutputReceiver.newInstance()

    doLast{
        bridge.devices.each {
            it.executeShellCommand("settings get global window_animation_scale", receiver)
            println "Value: ${receiver.getOutput()}"
        }
    }
}
```

The task prints the value for the window animation scale gathered by `receiver.getOutput()`.